# The Laravel registration page takes a long time to load

Tags: laravel, sqliteopenhelper

I just started using Laravel. I haven't written almost any code yet, the problem on my site is that it takes 120 seconds to load on the register page, there is no problem on other pages, but when I want to enter the register area, the page takes about 120 seconds to load, what can I do?

I couldn't change anything, I'm just experiencing this late loading in the register field can anyone help?[image: Late loading of the page]

Comment: check the console, if there are some scripts that are not fetched correctly!

Comment: The one in register.blade.php? I'm sorry, I'm very new to laravel, I can push you a little :)    https://www.hizliresim.com/3np19q8 can you review the picture TTFB response time is too long

Comment: no, i mean the console on your browser, in your screenshot there is a console tab, click there and check if you have any error related to javascript/css imports, those files, if are not found might slow down the page loading

Comment: console image like this https://prnt.sc/wvX_r4mVXzy7

Comment: as you can see, there are lot of failed requests for imports, fix those first, and then check if the speed changes.

Comment: Where can I fix it or disable it?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I removed the error css and js files, it was down to 120ms, but I can't find the map file https://prnt.sc/tyKlKqdnu1ze

Comment: if you are not using any css preprocessor, you don't need them, so just remove the imports in your view, tell me if that works, so i can write an answer about this

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time, I updated the css and js map files, the only problem remained. Dns lookup ms loading increased. How can I fix this?  https://prnt.sc/R0fz8dKzVs8A

Comment: you're welcome! if you are importing the css from an external url, i suggest that first you download the asset file, then you import it from your public path

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried all of them, still the same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1. If the required js vs. cs's for the error in the Software Console are not produced, you need to fill them again and again to reduce the failure. It can read files.

Set max_execution_time 120 to max_input_time -1 memory_limit to at least 512M. Cpanel operators Bug exercises editing controls and minimizes line spacing on those pages. You can easily use it with Laravel Debugbar so that you don't benefit from Cpanel. Finally not sure if it can be seen from DNS Ms, which may be caused by Server Location. Take it easy now. Sorry for the delay.